# Launcher Activity running before Broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

Houston I have a problem, here it goes:

I have a broadcast receiver that runs when my app is updated, I've achieved that using this:

Android **Manifest**, inside `<application>` tag:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".control.background.services.UpdateReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            <data android:scheme="package" android:path="br.com.soutsapp.waiter.soutsw" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```

And this **BroadcastReceiver** class:

```
public class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public UpdateReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED)){
            String packageName = context.getPackageName();
            if(packageName.equalsIgnoreCase("br.com.soutsapp.Souts_v3")){
                final Context appContext = context.getApplicationContext();

                SharedPreferences sp = appContext.getSharedPreferences(ConstantUtils.SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String json = sp.getString(ConstantUtils.TAG_SHARED_PREFERENCES_USER_INFO, null);

                UserModel user = null;
                if(json != null){
                    user = new JsonParserUtils<>(UserModel.class).serialize(json);
                }

                if(user != null && user.getFacebookUserId() != null && user.getFacebookUserId().length() > 0){
                    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(appContext);
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                }

                sp.edit().clear().commit();

                Log.d("SOUTS", "Running broadcast receiver");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside my Launcher activity I've printed a log when onCreate ends;

And I got this two prints, when my app runs with a update:

> 06-28 21:58:48.629 24984-24984/br.com.soutsapp.Souts_v3 D/SOUTS:
>   Running onCreate EstablishmentActivity
>
> 06-28 21:58:51.572 24984-24984/br.com.soutsapp.Souts_v3 D/SOUTS:
>   Running broadcast receiver

As you can see, broadcast receiver runs 3 seconds after the Launcher activity, so here goes my question, **is there a way to be sure that my BroadcastReceiver will run before my Launcher activity?**

If not, how would you suggest I workaround this?

Comment: When did you send broadcast message?

Comment: @MarkShen that's the point, It is triggered by the updated version, I don't know exactly when it's called.

Comment: Is app updated before launcher activity created? Or after?

Comment: When I run from android studio, it installs and runs the app at same time, maybe, that's the problem, I'm going to try do another test

Comment: @MarkShen I've tried that test, but It didn't worked. Here we go again.

Comment: Try installing app without android studio

Comment: @MarkShen that's what I've done, and didn't worked : /